# Would a compilation of pop music based on classical music be an appropriate question or community wiki?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

Creating a compendium of pop songs based on themes from classical pieces seems a useful and participation-generating topic for Music Fans.

On the other hand, there are *a lot* of songs in that list. Does the question fit as is? Does it fit better as a community wiki? Should I just post it and see what happens?

I seek the wisdom of the community.

Answer (score 0):

If it's posted, it should be a community wiki.

---

Additionally, I concur with your statement:

> *...there are a lot of songs in that list.*

With this point alone, it's probably best to narrow the scope of the post to a specific composer or piece:

> Compilation of modern era songs, inspired by Beethoven

Furthermore, why just [pop](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pop) music? Why not create regions for genres and use tables to display the information within:

###### Pop Songs

| Title | Artist | Inspirational Piece | Supporting Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Because | The Beatles | Moonlight Sonata | [Classic FM](https://www.classicfm.com/composers/beethoven/guides/beatles-because-beethoven-moonlight-sonata/) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I think this would be more useful to future readers than an astronomical list of titles inspired by various classical pieces.